# Using Strcmp with arguments

Tags: c, file, pointers, stdin, argv

```
if (strcmp(&(argv[i][0]),"-")==0){
fprintf(stderr,"invalid option: '-%c'\n",(argv[i][1]));}
```

I am trying to pass a flag '-g' as an argument and I want the code to recognize the '-' and print it as an invalid flag. This doesn't seem to work. What should I do?

Comment: `argv[i][0]` would be the first character of the `ith` argument, e.g. `'-'`.  Taking the address of that character is not what you want.  You should just compare it to the exact character, like this: `argv[i][0] == '-'`

Answer (score 3):

argv[i][0] is the first character in string argv[i].

use just `if (argv[i][0] == '-')` or `if (strncmp(argv[i],"-", 1) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The expression `&(argv[i][0])` is 100% equivalent to just `argv[i]`.  You cannot form a leading substring of a string that way.  For your particular task, it would be simpler to perform a single-`char` comparison via the `==` operator:

```
if (argv[i][0]) == '-') {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid option: '-%c'\n", argv[i][1]);
}
```